# JWPlayer playing all video automatically when I'm playing only one

Tags: javascript, video, jwplayer

I'm using JWPlayer and its JS api. All other things works fine but when I'm playing single video it plays all videos in page. I've given unique id to all videos.

Code :

```
var player = jwplayer('v-'+video.MediaGUID).setup({
                //file: image_server_path+'uploads/'+video.MediaFolder+'/'+video.ImageName+'.mp4',
                file: 'http://localhost/jwplayer/video/home-banner.mp4',
                mute: true,
                autostart: false,
                primary: 'flash'
              })
              .addButton(site_url+'assets/img/popin.png','popout video',function(){
                $scope.popout_video('v-'+video.MediaGUID);
              },"popoutvideo")
              .addButton(site_url+'assets/img/popout.png','popout close',function(){
                $scope.popin_video('v-'+video.MediaGUID);
              },"popoutclose");
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you detect which video is in visible state to user, set autostart property true to it; set autostart value to false by default;